# Relation between number of google search results from a phrase for a domain

Tags: seo, google, domains, google-search-console, google-search

The question is when I searched (in google) my researched keyword phrase (3 words) in google with quotes, it bring out about 145,000,000 results.

The competition is 0.01

Monthly global searches is 3,68,000

Monthly local searches is 4400

I have used match type as **"phrase"** in google keyword tool.

I just want to know whether the keyword phrase is **good for domain name** with respect to search results and Monthly global and local searches as given above.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a domain name with the keyword you want to rank well with in it, definitely do it. Keywords in domains carry a lot of weight. [Google is trying to reduce its value for obvious reasons](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-keyword-domains-13125.html) but even if it is reduced it still is a very good thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

I've read a lot of information on this topic and domain name is almost never used for page rank anymore.

Comment: Completely untrue

Comment: -1 [citation needed]